# how to include file which are located outside of the folder

Tags: php

I have create my  system of three folders

- pages folder
- style folder
- images folder

and one index.php file.

My problem is how I can include index.php file in my file login.php which are found in pages folder. 
I'm trying to header   ("Location:index.php") don't work.
Not: this index.php is single file located outside of those folders

```
<?php
  header  ("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Use <?php header ("Location: ../index.php"); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the URL's relative from the document root (by adding an initial `/`):

```
header('Location: /index.php');
```

or if you want to redirect to a sub folder:

```
header('Location: /theFolder/index.php');
```

Then you don't need to care what folder you're in and add a bunch of `../../`.

Answer (score 0):

When traversing a folder tree, you can use `../` to denote a parent folder.

`.` is a shortcut to 'the current folder'.
`..` is a shortcut to 'the folder containing the current folder'.

Assuming the `index.php` file is in the parent folder of the `login.php` page, you can access it like so:

`header ("Location: '../index.php'");`

Comment: What are the purpose of putting ../ at the starting?

Comment: yes it work ! but I'm got confussion on what are the aim of putting ../ at the starting? and it's only two fullstop (..) not otherwise when you put one don't work three don't work.why?

Comment: `../` means "go one folder up". You can chain them, `../../` means go two folders up.